# Username of smtp appearing in email while using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send email in the contact form. However in my sent email, the username used to validate the SMTP appears.For example consider the following

```
sender:a@b.com
receiver:c@d.com
smtp username:e@f.com
```

When the mail is sent, I get
a@b.com e@f.com

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Post minimal code to reproduce this please, otherwise we have no idea what you're on about.

Comment: $mail = new \PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = 'login';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Username = 'vidhya@iryaa.com';
$mail->Password = '/////';
//$mail->SetFrom('vidhya@iryaa.com', 'Example');
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $email_from);

//$mail->Subject = 'The subject';
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress('vidhya@iryaa.com');
$mail->Send();

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments, it makes a mess - Edit your post.